# Intel 4400 HD driver for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I am programming with OpenGL 4.3 and until now with Windows. I bought a X555LD and I am new to Ubuntu. the notebook has an Intel HD 4400 and a NVIDIA GeForce 820M graphic cards, but since I got my notebook (2 weeks) I am trying and testing almost all tutorials I have found in the internet.

When I terminal: glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"

It just says: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.0

My Question is: is there any opportunity to get OpenGL 4.3 on Ubuntu?

Sorry for my bad english.